# Avoid merging when switching from child branch to parent branch in Git

Tags: git

I had created a child branch using

> git checkout - b child_branch parent_branch.

I created some new files in my `child_branch`.

When I do git checkout `parent_branch`, I see the new files in my `parent_branch` as well. I don't want this. Does git by default do merge the modifications in old files (files which were there in parent and child inherited from parent) and also put the new files created in `child_branch` in `parent_branch` as well ? Also I want to avoid the merges for the old files and don't want to have new files in `parent_branch`. What should I do?

```
git checkout order
M     src/FileUtils.java
M     src/Manipulators.java
```

FileUtils.java and Manipulators.java are the new files which I created in the child branch order-test. I don't want the merge to happen.Also when I do checkout to order-test again, some files are again merged. Does this merging always happen between parent and child branches?

Also how should I revert back the merges that have happened ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't committed those files yet, and Git does not see them conflicting with the other branch you've transferred to.  If there *were* conflicts when you changed branches, Git would ask you to either commit or stash your changes instead.

To avoid this scenario, you should actually commit your changes first.

```
git add .
git commit
```